# Program to show receipt for shopping as list in box in java

Tags: java, swing

Hi I want to make app that will do this: ask How much products You want? then do loop for given amount of products and each time it loops ask for Product Name, Price, Vat and how much pieces of this product like first You want two products e.g. bread and butter so at first loop user inputs Bread, Netto, Price 2$, 20% VAT(to add) and enter that he/she wants to buy 2 breads and save all this then do same things for butter and then gives a list in box with all items listed together with the final price like both of them after adding VAT is 4.51 so here goes Total: 4.51$

```
package hello;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class okienko {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String s,t,y,g, h;
        float u,i5,i4,k, i, j,z, c=0, d=0;
        int a, b=0;
        s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ile towarów będziesz kupisz");
        z = Float.parseFloat(s);
        do{

            y = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"podaj nazwe towaru");
            s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "podaj ilosc towaru");


            j = Float.parseFloat(s);

            s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "podaj cene jednostkowa");

            k = Float.parseFloat(s);
            s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "podaj podatek");
            u = Float.parseFloat(s);
            i5=j*k*u/100;
            i4=j*k+i5;
            d=d+i5;
            c=c+i4;

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, y + "podatek vat = " + i5 + ", a wartosc koncowa = " + i4);

                b++;
        }while( b < z);

        System.exit(0);



    }
}
```

???
So now what I have to do in order to get box with list.

Regards.

Comment: I do not understand your question, and perhaps this is due to a language issue, but please try to clarify exactly what this code does and what you're asking.

Comment: So now I just need what I have to do in order to get box with list.

Comment: Please edit your original question and put all this information into the question.

Comment: here You go  :) hope it's ok now :)

Comment: [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) or [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

Comment: Thanks for help but when I try to use listModel = new DefaultListModel(); listModel.addElement("Jane Doe"); listModel.addElement("John Smith"); listModel.addElement("Kathy Green"); list = new JList(listModel); after adding import java.awt.*; eclipse says it cant find such objectand won't be able to run. what's wrong???

Comment: Did you actually declare a variable for `listModel = new DefaultListModel()` and `list = new JList(listModel);`? If you pasted what you have there as-is, then of course it would yell at you that those objects don't exist, because you haven't declared them. Also, those classes also require a type parameter, so you should probably use DefaultListModel<String> and JList<String> to keep yourself type-safe.

Comment: So by far i understand that it should be lik 'a= listModel = new DefaultListModel<string>()' and 'b=list = new JList<string>(listModel);'. Right?